# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am new to Python and currently having trouble when **importing** some libraries.

I am using Python 3.8.

I have installed Pandas in the CMD using "pip install pandas"

If i go to Python folder i see that Pandas is installed:

C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages

But then i get this error message when trying to import Pandas in my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\VALENTINA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have this error message when running my script in Visual Code and also in IDLE.

I appreciate if someone can help me

Thnks

Comment: You're not using virtual environments or similar tools? Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: Im using Pyhton 3.8 and Visual studio Code as text editor

Comment: are you running the code in VS Code or at the command line? Sometimes VS Code will default to another python install if you have python2 installed

Comment: @Valentina Please marked the question as solved. Also, it's better to use anaconda to install Python as it comes with common packages required in most cases.

Answer (score 25):

I was facing the same problem. I am using `python 3.7.5`. By default `pip install pandas` command install version 1.0.3. So i revert to version 1.0.1.

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

Now it is working without error. You may try it.

Comment: thanks i also installed a previous version and was able to solve the problem

Comment: I had the same problem with the following case and this solution worked excellent for me: exe created with Python 3.8.2, Pyinstaller 3.6 on Windows 7. Program should run on Windows 10. With pandas 1.0.3, the exe was working on windows 7 but not on 10. Thank you!

Comment: same problem here with pandas 1.0.4

Comment: Same problem here with Pandas 1.0.5 on Python 3.8.3 64 bit for Windows 10. Installing 1.0.1 worked out fine. Now the question is why?

Answer (score 8):

You may also try to install a fresher version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.

E.g. (2015-2019)

I had the same problem, and installing the aforementioned resolved it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Did you have pandas 1.0.3 while posting this solution?

Comment: I had pandas 1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

There are two error messages I have received in importing pandas, the one in the OP and the other one being

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'
```

I was able to mitigate the issues by reinstalling the package/library

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

as another user pointed out before me. I am using Python 3.8.2 in conjunction with pandas 1.0.1 without hiccup now.

Answer (score 2):

simply uninstall pandas and reinstall pandas to 1.0.1

eg:
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error (Python 3.9). This solved it:

```
pip uninstall pandas
upgrade pip=21.3.1
pip install pandas
```

Comment: I'm guessing that should read "upgrade," not "upgrape"?