# i keep trying to run an attribute of pandas on jupiter notebook but i keep getting an error. can you help me out on what to do?

Tags: pandas

here's my code

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6,], [10, 20, 30]])
```

and here is the error message

```
AttributeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

ipython-input-3-12e99d5ada70> in <module>

----> 1 df1 = pandas.DataFrame([[2, 4, 6], [10, 20, 30]])

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

Comment: Do you accidentally have a self-created file named `pandas.py` in your current path?

Comment: i don't think so... i installed pandas using pip in the command line

Comment: You can `import os` and then `os.listdir()` to see if there's a `pandas.py` where you are working. Otherwise, perhaps the pandas installation was unsuccessful.

Comment: It isn't in my os.listdir()

Comment: After importing pandas, if you just type `pandas` in a cell and run the cell, what does it output?

Comment: No it doesn't when I run pandas in the command line I get a bunch of errors with the last line saying "dll load file failed" but I can import it in jupyter notebook

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767017/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-aggregations-the-specified-module. It sounds like downgrading pandas from 1.0.3 to 1.0.1 helped.