# DLL load failed installing pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following error message when I am trying to install pandas library.

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

Cell In[1], line 1

----> 1 import pandas

File \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pandas_*init*_.py:59

```
 56 # let init-time option registration happen

 57 import pandas.core.config_init  # pyright: ignore[reportUnusedImport] # noqa: F401
```

---> 59 from pandas.core.api import (

```
 60     # dtype

 61     ArrowDtype,

 62     Int8Dtype,

 63     Int16Dtype,

 64     Int32Dtype,

 65     Int64Dtype,

 66     UInt8Dtype,

 67     UInt16Dtype,

 68     UInt32Dtype,

 69     UInt64Dtype,

 70     Float32Dtype,

 71     Float64Dtype,

 72     CategoricalDtype,

 73     PeriodDtype,

 74     IntervalDtype,

 75     DatetimeTZDtype,
```

...

```
 15     is_datetime64_ns_dtype,

 16     is_numeric_dtype,

 17 )
```

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767017/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-aggregations-the-specified-module